# Crash on vector pop_back() of only remaining entry

Tags: c++, vector, crash

### Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

struct myClass {
    bool bIsDead;
    myClass(bool bDead) {
        this->bIsDead = bDead;
    }
};

void PrintVector(std::vector<myClass*> vec) {
    std::cout << "The vector contains: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vec[i]->bIsDead << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::srand(std::time(0)); // use current time as seed for rng

    std::vector<myClass*> myVector;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int tempRand = std::rand() % 2;
//      int tempRand = 1;
        if(tempRand == 1) {
            myVector.push_back(new myClass(true));
        }
        else {
            myVector.push_back(new myClass(false));
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Unsorted: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);

    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [ ]( const myClass *lhs, const myClass *rhs )
    {
        return lhs->bIsDead < rhs->bIsDead;
    });

    std::cout << "Sorted: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);


    while(myVector.back()->bIsDead) {
        delete myVector.back();
        myVector.pop_back();
    }

    std::cout << "Removed Dead Ones: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output for random inputs:

```
Unsorted: 
The vector contains: 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
Sorted: 
The vector contains: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
Removed Dead Ones: 
The vector contains: 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Hit ENTER to continue...
```

#### Output for all 1's (i.e. pop_back removes all):

```
Unsorted: 
The vector contains: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Sorted: 
The vector contains: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

Hit ENTER to continue...
```

For this console application I'm not given any errors or crash warnings, but it isn't outputting the two cout statements after the pop_back call for the all 1's case.

Any ideas on why popping a vector of pointers back to empty causes the program to crash?

Comment: while(myVector.back()->bIsDead) what will happen if the myVector is empty?

Comment: Waaay too long. Anyway, look at the `while(myVector.back()->bIsDead)` loop and [explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Ohh... It's not the pop_Back that's causing the crash, it's the while loop's next .back() check that's causing the crash. I should be able to simply add a 'if(empty) { break; }' to fix that then.

Comment: Just use a for loop instead of a while to `delete` elements, then call `myVector.clear()` when you're done.

Comment: The problem there is that I don't want to delete all of the elements all of the time. This sorts the vector so that the ones I want to delete are at the back where I can easily just pop them off until all the ones I want gone, are gone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I really appreciate that you put so much effort into your question. However, the next time you run into a problem, you should really try to remove more of your code. This it not always easy but makes finding the error much simpler. In your case, you could e.g. easily delete all the random filling and sorting, as you have already established that the problem only occurs when the vector is completely filled with dead elements.

Comment: Good to know. After spending 3 hours trying to figure it out, I just wanted to make sure other people had all the info they needed to figure it out. Didn't think about the whole wading through code part of it.

Comment: @FriedYeti Trust me when I say most of the information in your question is utterly useless.

Comment: So partition according to isDead, then delete and clear the 1/2 you don't wan to keep.

Comment: Just to put my previous comment into context: Your question is/was imho still much better than what most people throw at SO on their first try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check for size of vector. It shouldn't be 0 if you want to access the vector's last element using `back()`.

Change this:

```
while(myVector.back()->bIsDead) {
```

to:

```
while(myVector.size() > 0 && myVector.back()->bIsDead) {
```

Here's the correct code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

struct myClass {
    bool bIsDead;
    myClass(bool bDead) {
        this->bIsDead = bDead;
    }
};

void PrintVector(std::vector<myClass*> vec) {
    std::cout << "The vector contains: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vec[i]->bIsDead << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::srand(std::time(0)); // use current time as seed for rng

    std::vector<myClass*> myVector;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int tempRand = std::rand() % 2;
//      int tempRand = 1;
        if(tempRand == 1) {
            myVector.push_back(new myClass(true));
        }
        else {
            myVector.push_back(new myClass(false));
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Unsorted: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);

    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [ ]( const myClass *lhs, const myClass *rhs )
    {
        return lhs->bIsDead < rhs->bIsDead;
    });

    std::cout << "Sorted: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);


    while(myVector.size() > 0 && myVector.back()->bIsDead) {
        delete myVector.back();
        myVector.pop_back();
    }

    std::cout << "Removed Dead Ones: " << std::endl;
    PrintVector(myVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Quoting [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/)

> Calling this function(back()) on an empty container causes undefined
>   behavior.

PS: You don't need to make the question look so intimidating to grab our attention.

Comment: I previously did a check of `(myVector.back()->bIsDead && !myVector.empty())` but since I was checking bIsDead on an empty before checking if it wasn't empty it still crashed.

Comment: PS: I didn't try to make it look intimidating, I just wanted to put all the info into it that would be needed. I spent about 3 hours trying to find out why pop_back() was crashing it and figured it was something more complicated since I made sure it was empty before popping the back.

Comment: Yes, in case of && operator the first condition is checked and if it is true then the second one is checked. So you need to check for empty before accessing the element. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As with most problems I have, it was something simple. Thanks to billz and juanchopanza's comments it was pointed out to me that it wasn't the `pop_back()` that was crashing, but rather the subsequent `back()` called in the while loop.

This is easily fixable in several ways, 2 examples being:
adding `if(myVector.empty) {break;}` into the delete's while loop
or like [user3286661](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911598/6935483) said, adding a conditional to the while loop first checking if it has an element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access `myVector.back()` even when the vector is already empty.

The least intrusive solution (minimal modification to your code) I can think of would this:

```
while (!myVector.empty() && myVector.back()->bIsDead) {
    delete myVector.back();
    myVector.pop_back();
}
```

The "right" thing to do would be to use either `std::vector<myClass>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myClass>>` (no need for manual delete) and use the [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
myVector.erase(
    std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 
        [](const auto& p) {
            return p->bIsDead; //p.bIsDead for std::vector<myClass>
        }
    ), 
    myVector.end()
);
```

This might look more complicated, but it is safer (no accidental memory leaks), probably more efficient and **makes the call to `sort` unnecessary**.